# Dynamically changing background color of all html elements with same class failing

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, servlets

I'm trying to dynamically update the background colors of certain elements using ajax, jsp and a servlet call. I've included my js functions and also a screenshot of my servlet and console log. The code is running all of the lines, yet nothing is changing on the front end. Really appreciate the help! I also tried making another JS function to handle the bg changes but that did not help at all.

```
        <script>
         function validate() {
                 console.log("hello");
              var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
              xhttp.open("GET", "/"+window.location.pathname.split("/")[1]+"/HomeServlet?inputName=" + document.searchform.search.value, false);
              xhttp.send();
              if (xhttp.responseText.trim().length > 0) {
                    console.log("in if statement " + xhttp.responseText);
                    var str = xhttp.responseText;
                    var result = str.split(" ");
                    console.log("str " + str + " - result: " + result + " result size = " + result.length);
                    for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                        console.log("in first loop");
                        console.log("value:" + result[i]);
                        elements = document.getElementsByClassName(result[i]);
                        console.log("elements: " + elements.length);
                        for (var j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
                            console.log("in the loop");
                            //elements[j].style.backgroundColor = "red";
                            changeBg(elements[j]);
                        }
                    } 
                //return false;
              }
              return true;
          }
         function changeBg(element) {
                alert(window.getComputedStyle(element).backgroundColor);
                element.style.color = "red";

            }
        </script>
```

In my browser, my console reads the following proving that the code is running every line, included outputting the alert box yet not changing the element.style.color or backgroundColor since I've tried both.

Comment: You are changing the *text* colour (`element.style.color`) instead of  the *background* colour `element.style.backgroundColor` in changeBg()

Answer (score 0):

please use

> element.style.backgroundColor

instead of

> element.style.color

because `style.color` is to change font color, not for background color

Answer (score 0):

I think best solution will be adding style with new colors for classes.

```js
var counter = 0;
  function changeBG(){
   counter++;
   var css = '.testBGclasss { background: '+(counter%2?'red':'blue')+'; }',
    head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    style = document.createElement('style');

   style.type = 'text/css';
   if (style.styleSheet){
     style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
   } else {
     style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
   }

   head.appendChild(style);
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
 <div class="testBGclasss">
  <h1>Some text<h1>
 </div>
 <input type="button" value="change background" onclick="changeBG()"/>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help. I ended up figuring it out. Turns out you can't dynamically keep parts of a form changed.